# C++ OpenGL bounce object from point to point

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glew

I am just asking for help with bouncing a cube between two x,y co-ordinates. These x,y coordinates are represented by circles, and I've set my program up so that these circles can be moved.

My Current program is kind of working, but when point on the right gets lower than the point on the left, the object won't go below the left object. Same thing for the left circle if it gets higher than the right.

I have access to the X,Y co-ordinates of the two points and the X,Y co-ordinates of the bouncing cube.

At the moment, I have been gradually updating the cube's GLtrasnatef(x,y,z) method with an xRate and a yRate in a glutTimerFunc.

yRate = (abs(y2-y1)/distanceBetween2points;

xRate = (abs(x2-x1)/distanceBetween2points;

I want to start fresh because my code is getting clustered, and I'm not really sure if there is already an algorithm for gradually translating an object between two points

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are taking the absolute value of the distance between the two points, which is why your movement gets artificially constrained.

For gradual interpolation between two values, [smoothstep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) is used quite often.

Comment: Hey, I checked out your link, in the example there is a method called 'clamp' do you know what that does haha? Cheers

Comment: Clamp constrains a value between a min and max value.